The nature of the issue—restricted outgoing traffic and inability to find the local cache
i have been working in collab pro.i have upload all model files correctly from hugging face but still got this problem
huggingface_hub.utils._errors.LocalEntryNotFoundError: Cannot find an appropriate cached snapshot folder for the specified revision on the local disk and outgoing traffic has been disabled. To enable repo look-ups and downloads online, pass 'local_files_only=False' as input.
please anyone can explain this error and tell me teh ways to solve it
